# What type of colloquialism is 'soon as it ready'?

Tags: colloquialisms

I am wondering if there is a specific name for the type of speech pattern (I am not sure if that is the right term) or vernacular used below.

**Example:**
"I'll beep you, soon as it ready."

Being a contraction of "I'll beep you, as soon as it's ready".

*Also, please tell me if I should improve the title/clarity of my question.*

Comment: That sounds to me like a poor attempt at mimicking some varieties of Oriental English.

Comment: I've heard and consider standard *soon as it's ready* but not *soon as it ready*.

Comment: @HotLicks no, a white character says it in Seinfeld.

Comment: @XdakutWizzlekrank - That doesn't say it's not a mimic.

Comment: @HotLicks Would you trust my word that I know for certain that the character in question is not mimicking broken english?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [zero copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)#Zero_copula). According to Wikipedia:

> In informal speech of English, the copula may be dropped, as in the sentence, "She a nurse". It is a feature of African American vernacular English but is also used by a variety of other English speakers in informal contexts. An example is the sentence "I saw twelve men, each a soldier".

Comment: I guess that's it :)